# How do I navigate to my previous page when an option from the list is not selected?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

My app has the following Navigation scheme:
Settings -> Colors -> Add Color. Add Color page is a List View. When a choose a color, I navigate back to the "Colors" page. However, if I click on the back button on top of the "Add Color" page I navigate back to the  "Settings" page. How do I fix this so that I navigate back to the "Colors" page?

AddColorFragment.java

```
public class AddColorFragment extends BaseTeamsFragment {

public static AddColorFragment newInstance() {
    return new AddColorFragment();
}

private ListView mListColors;

@Override
protected int getFragmentLayout() {
    return R.layout.fragment_add_color;
}

@Override
protected void setViewBindings(View view) {
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initializeView();
}

@Override
protected BaseViewModel onCreateViewModel() {
    return null;
}

private void initializeView() {
    Context context = getContext();
    if (context == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Code to Populate the colors list

    // Save understood language
    mListColors.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            // save color in DB
            NavigationService.navigateToRoute(getContext(), RouteNames.COLORS);
            finishActivity();
        }
    });

}

private void finishActivity() {
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        getActivity().finish();
    }
}
}
```

My Activity file is as follows

```
public class AddColorActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserBIType.PanelType getPanelType() {
        return UserBIType.PanelType.settings;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.activity_add_color;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
        NavigationService.navigateToRoute(this, RouteNames.SETTINGS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initialize(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTitle(R.string.add_color);
    }
 }
```

My fragment XML file is as follows:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/colors_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should capture the `onBackPressed()` in the Activity and send an event to the `Fragment`.

In turn the `Fragment` should chck if it has to do anything with that event, and return `true` if it did something, or `false` if had nothing to do.

Again in the `Activity`, if it receives `true` as response, it doesn't do anything else, and if it receives `false`, if goes ahead and calls `super.onBackPressed()` which will do the default of closing the current activity and going back to the previous one.

Comment: Sorry, I did not follow your suggestion. I have added my Activity and fragment XML code. Can you please elaborate on the solution you suggested

Comment: I was coding an example and I it is not clear to me why you have set NavigationService.navigateToRoute(this, RouteNames.SETTINGS); in the AddColorActivity if that activity should return to the COLOR activity according to your explanation. Also I am not sure how NavegationService works, doest it only start activities?

Answer (score 0):

**You should call onBackPressed() instead of finishActivity(), when you click on listView**